# Compiler error C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data

Tags: c++, linux, windows, stdvector

I am trying to use std::count over std::vector as following:

```
int count = std::count( stdVector.begin(), stdVector.end(), "element" );
```

On windows, it gives the following compiler error.

`error C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data`

If I change the code as following on `Windows` compiler does not appear.

```
auto count = std::count( stdVector.begin(), stdVector.end(), "element" );
```

However, now I face the following error on linux for the above change.

`error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'count' with no type`

How would I use `std::count` which will get build on both the platform without any error?

Comment: Are you sure it is an error, or a [compile-time warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th7a07tz.aspx) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things that can conflict differently in different environments:

The first is `auto` as a deduced type is a C++11 feature. May be the linux compiler does not have it as a default (just use `-std=c++11`, and if it does not have it, upgrade!)

The other is that the return type of std::count is `size_t`, not `int`, and `size_t` to `int` conversion may lose data depending on on how `size_t` is defined (there is at least a signed / unsigned mismatch and eventually a different in size of the two types, like 32 bit for `int` and 64 bit for `size_t`).

Answer (score 7):

The reason you get this warning is that on a 64 bit build, the standard containers use 64 bit values for size types, and implicitly converting a 64 bit value (e.g. `size_t`) to a 32 bit value  (e.g. `int`) can  lose data.

The actual data type returned by the `count` function, which in this case would be `std::vector<T>::difference_type`, is probably the best type to use if your compiler doesn't support `auto`. Using `size_t` would probably work without warning as well, and is a lot shorter to type.

Alternatively, if you're not bothered by the risk of data loss (e.g. are never planning to have more than 2^32-1 objects in the container) you can simply cast the warning away:

```
int count = static_cast<int>( std::count(stdVector.begin(), stdVector.end(), "element") );
```

Comment: Yuck for casting. Better not to even suggest it. Much better to use the correct variable type.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen size_t, ptrdiff_t and the likes are platform-dependent, and sometimes you need an exact size.
Also, in this specific case, it might be a very reasonable assumption that this vector is never going to contain more elements than an int can count.